# How do I fix this error " Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"?

Tags: deployment, vbscript

I'm writing this script to help with logging when my workplace re-images computers. The problem is that I am somewhat inexperienced with VBS and troubleshooting VBS scripts.

This script is built to take in an argument and log the section indicated by the argument. Ex: Someone passes in /1 and then the script logs section 1.

Here is the full script(with some elements redacted).

```
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Dim strDriveLetter, strRemotePath, strusername, strpassword, strRemoteNewPath

WScript.sleep 5000

Dim iRetVal
Dim sCmd

Dim begImg, begDrivers, begAppInstalls, finalCheck, finalConfig, complete

set begImg = WScript.Arguments
set begDrivers = WScript.Arguments
set begAppInstalls = WScript.Arguments
set finalCheck = WScript.Arguments
set finalConfig = WScript.Arguments
set complete = WScript.Arguments

'my solution
set sequence = Wscript.Arguments



sCmd = "Net use L: /del"
iRetVal = WshShell.Run(sCmd, 0, true)

strDriveLetter = "L:"
strRemotePath = "\\FileServ1\LogShare"
strRemoteNewPath = "\\FileServ1\LogShare"
strusername = "domain\admin"
strpassword = "password"


objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDriveLetter, strRemotePath, , strusername, strpassword

'|------------------------------------|
'|   Get Serial Number                |
'| Variable objSN = Machine Serial #  |
'|------------------------------------|
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colBIOS = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_BIOS")
For each objBIOS in colBIOS
    objSN = objBIOS.SerialNumber
Next


' This appears to be the first part  1
'|--------------------------------------|
'|   Create Text File with Machine S/N  |
'|--------------------------------------|
'8 is ForAppending
If sequence = 1 Then 
Set trs = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strDriveLetter & "\" & objSN & ".txt", 8, True)
trs.WriteLine ""
trs.WriteLine "*************************************************************************"
trs.WriteLine(Now & " BEGINNING IMAGING SESSION ON: " & objSN)
trs.WriteLine(Now & " mapped " & strRemotePath & " as " & strDriveLetter)
trs.WriteLine(Now & " Beginning to apply image...")
trs.WriteLine ""
End If

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    trs.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<----------ERROR---------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Error: " & Err.Number )
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Error (Hex): " & Hex(Err.Number ))
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Source: " &  Err.Source )
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Description: " &  Err.Description )
    Err.Clear
    trs.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<----------ERROR---------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
End If   


' Part 2
'|--------------------------------------|
'|   BEGIN DRIVER AND WINDOWS UPDATES   |
'|--------------------------------------|
If sequence = 2 Then 
trs.WriteLine(Now & " IMAGE APPLIED; BEGINNING DRIVERS AND WINDOWS UPDATES...")
trs.WriteLine ""
End If

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    trs.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<----------ERROR---------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Error: " & Err.Number )
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Error (Hex): " & Hex(Err.Number ))
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Source: " &  Err.Source )
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Description: " &  Err.Description )
    Err.Clear
    trs.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<----------ERROR---------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
End If


'Part 3
'|----------------------------------------------------------|
'|   APPLY UPDATES AND DRIVERS, GO TO APPLICATION INSTALLS  |
'|----------------------------------------------------------|
If sequence = 3 Then 
trs.WriteLine(Now & " INITIAL UPDATES AND DRIVERS APPLIED; PROCEEDING TO APPLICATION INSTALLS...")
End If

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    trs.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<----------ERROR---------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Error: " & Err.Number )
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Error (Hex): " & Hex(Err.Number ))
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Source: " &  Err.Source )
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Description: " &  Err.Description )
    Err.Clear
    trs.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<----------ERROR---------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
End If

'Part 4
'|--------------------------------------|
'|   STARTING FINAL CHECKS              |
'|--------------------------------------|
If sequence = 4 Then 
trs.WriteLine(Now & " APPLICATIONS COMPLETE; STARTING FINAL CHECK FOR UPDATES...")
trs.WriteLine ""
End If

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    trs.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<----------ERROR---------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Error: " & Err.Number )
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Error (Hex): " & Hex(Err.Number ))
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Source: " &  Err.Source )
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Description: " &  Err.Description )
    Err.Clear
    trs.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<----------ERROR---------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
End If


'Part 5
'|--------------------------------------|
'|   FINAL CONFIGURATIONS               |
'|--------------------------------------|
'8 is ForAppending
'Set trs = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strDriveLetter & "\" & objSN & ".txt", 8, True)     - I might need to delete this to make sure its on the same txt file
If sequence = 5 Then 
trs.WriteLine(Now & " UPDATES COMPLETE; PROCEEDING TO FINAL CONFIGURATIONS...")
trs.WriteLine ""
End If

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    trs.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<----------ERROR---------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Error: " & Err.Number )
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Error (Hex): " & Hex(Err.Number ))
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Source: " &  Err.Source )
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Description: " &  Err.Description )
    Err.Clear
    trs.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<----------ERROR---------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
End If

'Part 6
'this should be the final part
'|--------------------------------------|
'|   IMAGING SESSION COMPLETE           |
'|--------------------------------------|
If sequence = 6 Then 
trs.WriteLine(Now & " FINAL CONFIGURATION COMPLETE; IMAGING SESSION COMPLETE...")
trs.WriteLine "*************************************************************************"
'Use netbeans to remove the following 4 spaces if necessary
trs.WriteLine ""
trs.WriteLine ""
trs.WriteLine ""
trs.WriteLine ""
End If

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    trs.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<----------ERROR---------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Error: " & Err.Number )
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Error (Hex): " & Hex(Err.Number ))
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Source: " &  Err.Source )
    trs.WriteLine(Now & ":  Description: " &  Err.Description )
    Err.Clear
    trs.WriteLine("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<----------ERROR---------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
End If

trs.close

wscript.quit
```

Here is my input: `cscript OneScriptRuleThemAll.vbs  /1`

Here is the output and error message: `OneScriptToRuleThemAll.vbs(55, 1)   Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment`

From what I can tell I am not putting in the wrong number of arguments and I don't see the problem with my property assignments.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is occurring on the line `If sequence = 1 Then` For your intent to work, you need to change it to `If sequence.Item(0) = 1 Then`

Your arguments can continue to go from 1 to 6.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try to implement this and let you know if it works. I won't be back in the office until either late Friday or Monday.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the if statements are not being used to take the input of the parameters properly. Why is there an error check after each if? it seems like it could just be one big if statement.

Answer (score -1):

Your arguments are a collection so are in the form

```
    Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
    If LCase(Arg(0)) = "menu" or LCase(Arg(0)) = "m" then
    ShowMenu
    ...
```

1st is 0, 2nd is 1, etc